# Access-Control-Allow-Origin SESSION No work except only in localhost

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

I'm developping an android applicatiion but i have just one problem to finish,
the application get the News in a external web site and it use `SESSION` (PHP), for this i use

> Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*

to Access to the data. In localhost (Wamp) it work parfectly but when I am online the `SESSION` not work!
How can i resolve it?

It can help: I use AJAX and JQUERY

Comment: I'm missing the link between sessions and CORS?

Comment: SESSION and Access control headers have absolutely nothing to do with each other

Comment: Ok why in localhost it work but not online?